# How to transfer a variable from one workbook macro to another?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have a couple of workbooks that each create their own report and use the variable "Period" and each workbook has `Public Period as String` in a standard module.

I created a separate workbook that I use to open each of the individual workbooks and run the macros stored in those individual workbooks like this:

```
Application.Run ("'" & ReportBook.Name & "'!RunModel")
```

However, in this new workbook where I call to all the other workbooks and macros I assign the Period variable a value, but when Period comes up in the individual workbook macros, it is empty.

How do I keep those variable assignments across workbooks and macros?

Comment: Pass the variable value as parameters of the called macro, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/call-excel-macros

Comment: @VincentG I tried this, but I get syntax errors everytime I attempt to add parameters. Application.Run ("'" & ReportBook.Name & "'!RunModel") works but Application.Run ("'" & ReportBook.Name & "'!RunModel", Period) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by passing the variables as parameters and also (for some reason) it was necessary to remove parenthesis. Working code:

```
Application.Run "'" & ReportBook.Name & "'!RunModel", Period
```

Comment: Never use parenthesis when the return value of the sub/function is discarded